# plot a signal and mark the peaks position

Tags: matlab

I am trying to plot a signal and mark the peaks position as shown below in the figure:[image]

I already have the signal, values and location of each peak, but I couldn't put all of them together in the same graph, any help?

My code:

```
%signal is a vector which carries all the points of the signal 
figure;
[PKS,LOCS] = findpeaks(signal);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it not just a matter of plotting the peaks on top of the existing signal plot? Something like:

```
plot(t,signal,'b-',t(LOCS),signal(LOCS),'bv');
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @am .. It worked fine but is it possible to draw the triangles in a different color?

Comment: Yes, just change `bv` to `rv` or whatever you want. Check the documentation at http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/plot.html#inputarg_LineSpec for more details. Please accept the answer if it solved your problem.