# Selecting data from plot for echo duration in matlab

Tags: matlab, select, plot

Basically, i want to create a variable called "echo duration" from a plot. So, i have a plot of some echo traces from an echosounder, with x axis is sample number and y axis is voltage. What i want to do is to select all the highest voltage from all echo traces plot as my echo duration. Could that be done in Matlab?
Here is my code

```
File_33KHz              =fopen('TEdH.LF','r');
Bin_33KHz               =fread(File_33KHz,[Set_RecordLength,Set_PingNumber],'uint8');
File_200KHz             =fopen('TEdH.HF','r');
Bin_200KHz              =fread(File_200KHz,[Set_RecordLength,Set_PingNumber],'uint8');

figure;1;
EchoTraces_33KHz        =plot(Bin_33KHz(:,:));
title('Echo Trace Samples For 33KHz Transducer');                         
xlabel('Sample Number');                                                  
ylabel('Voltage');                                                         
figure;2;
EchoTraces_200KHz       =plot(Bin_200KHz(:,1:100:821));                    
title('Echo Trace Samples For 200KHz Transducer');                         
xlabel('Sample Number');                                                   
ylabel('Voltage');                                                         
legend('Sample Number','Voltage');
```

Please explain it in simple language, for i am a beginner in matlab programming. Thank you for your help

Comment: Adding a plot and/or sample input data may be useful.

Comment: Is your problem about finding peaks in a 2D plot? [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26755326/plot-a-signal-and-mark-the-peaks-position) or [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28712464/how-to-label-plot-having-peaks-in-matlab) may be interesting.